# Toggle svg visibility

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm using html buttons to toggle full screen width SVG images on and off. The images are separate SVG files. By making the SVGs full width, they scale to different landscape dimensions. Works OK, but the button layout doesn't scale well with the SVGs. My idea was to make a button panel as an SVG with clickable areas that would mimic the html buttons. However I can't work out a way of calling the javascript toggle function in the html page from the SVG clickable areas. I tried to make a simplified example as below.

In the simplified example I try and toggle layer02.svg as visible or hidden when I click on a shape defined in layer01.svg.

Can I call a "toggle" function in the html from an "onclick" in layer01.svg along the lines of:
<rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" onclick=...

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. Any help appreciated!

html:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .layer{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;  
      width:100%;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #controlLayer{
      visibility: visible;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggleLayer(){
        var svgLayer = document.getElementById("layer02");
        if (window.getComputedStyle(svgLayer).visibility === "hidden") {
            svgLayer.style.visibility='visible';
        } else {
           svgLayer.style.visibility='hidden';
        }
      }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
      <embed id="controlLayer" class="layer" src="layer01.svg" >
      <embed id="layer02" class="layer" src="layer02.svg" >
    </body>
    </html>
```

layer01.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="1920" height="890" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 508 235.48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >

<g stroke-width=".79375">
<rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" fill="#ff0" onclick="toggleLayer()"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

layer02.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="1920" height="890" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 508 235.48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
 <rect x="193.1" y="30.167" width="138.47" height="171.17" fill="#f00" stroke-width=".79375"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and share a [mcve]?

Comment: Use the [ <> ] button on the editor toolbar to convert your code into a SO snippet we can play with

Comment: I've put the html into a snippet - not sure what to do with the SVG's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `visibility: hidden`, your `#controlLayer` is underneath the `#layer02` in the z-index and cannot actually be clicked -- `#controlLayer` is essentially covered by an invisible `#layer02`. I've brought the SVGs directly into the below code for a functioning demo. Your SVGs are enormous and I've changed width/height to display in the space provided.

Additionally, Chrome88 gives an `Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleLayer is not defined` error. I haven't been able to find documentation for embed with SVGs but, assuming they function similar to iframes, they may not be able to access the DOM which includes your script and function.

```html
<style>
.layer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;  
  width:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#controlLayer{
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<!-- <embed id="layer02" class="layer" src="layer02.svg"> -->
<svg width="508" height="235.48" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 508 235.48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="layer02" class="layer"> 
<rect x="193.1" y="30.167" width="138.47" height="171.17" fill="red" stroke-width=".79375"/>
</svg>
<!-- <embed id="controlLayer" class="layer" src="layer01.svg" > -->
<svg width="508" height="235.48" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 508 235.48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="controlLayer" class="layer">
<rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" fill="blue" onclick="toggleLayer()"/>
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleLayer(){
    var svgLayer = document.getElementById("layer02");
    if (window.getComputedStyle(svgLayer).visibility === "hidden") {
        svgLayer.style.visibility='visible';
    } else {
        svgLayer.style.visibility='hidden';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yup - Thanks for the hint on the z-order- if I bring my "button panel" SVG in-line with the html and use z-order to keep it on top, I can call the javascript functions in the html to toggle the visibility of the other, external, SVGs.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite close. I am actually not sure why it's not working. Something reproducible is always easier to follow (as mentioned by @evolutionxbox).

For me it's easiest to reference with the element id.

I hope the following snippet can help:

```js
function hideSVG() {
  var style = document.getElementById("rect").style.display;
  if (style === "none") document.getElementById("rect").style.display = "block";
  else document.getElementById("rect").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Click the blue circle
    <p />
    <svg width="500" height="500">
      <rect id=rect class="shape" width="100" height="100" />
      <circle id=circ class="shape" cx="120" cy="120" r="60" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" onclick="hideSVG()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My SVGs are in separate files from the html page - which is, I think, where my difficultly lies. This is an example using html buttons. My idea is to replace the html button panel by an SVG with clickable areas to do the toggling. But then how to invoke a function in the html page from the SVG file?